# Django Pagination - Object list not looping in template

Tags: django, pagination, django-views, django-templates

I'm attempting to use pagination on my notifications page for a user (list of all notifications). When I add the code for pagination:

```
def notificationList(request, pk):

    notifications = Notification.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(notifications, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        notifications = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        notifications = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        notifications = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'notifications': notifications }
    return render(request, 'user/notifications.html', context)
```

The result is this:
[image: Image of notifications page]

However, when I comment out all pagination related code in `views.py`, all the notifications appear on the page (pagination appears). So I know it's not that I'm not accessing my notification object list incorrectly/returning an empty queryset. Here is the `notifications.html` pagination code:

```
{% if notifications.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    {% if notifications.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ notifications.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in notifications.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if notifications.number == i %}
        <li class="active page-item"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only page-item">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if notifications.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ notifications.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Here is where I render the notifications in the template:

```
                {% for notification in notifications %}
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      {% if notification.read == False %}
                        <span class="badge badge-primary">New</span>
                      {% elif notification.read == True %}
                        <span class="badge badge-success">Read</span>
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'offer-details' notification.offer_id %}">View</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      {% if notification.type_of_notification == "O" %}
                        <p>An offer has been made for one of your repairs!</p>
                      {% elif notification.type_of_notification == "P" %}
                        <p>A payment has been made on a repair!</p>
                      {% elif notification.type_of_notification == "OR" %}
                        <p>Sorry, your offer for a repair has been rejected.</p>
                      {% elif notification.type_of_notification == "OC" %}
                        <p>An offer for your repair has been canceled!</p>
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      {{notification.created_at}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show where you *render* the items in your template?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay I've add where the items are rendered. Again, when I remove all of the pagination code from views.py, the notification items in the for loop render perfectly.

Comment: @AustinBurke hey, are you using django-notifations? what did u end up doing?